# How to access to dynamic element generated by javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

I try set default(selected value) for select before boostrap-table starting to render.
I am successly created for select change event, but failed to create on page loading.
Please  show me right direction....

Latest version used of Jquery 3.6 and bootstap-table 1.21.3
Html code:

```
<body>
  <div style="position:relative;width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">

    <div class="toolbar" style="border: 1px solid red;width: 100%;padding:2px;">
         <!--Here you can write extra buttons/actions for the toolbar--> 
          <select class="form-select" aria-live="polite" id="jails" name="jails">
          
          </select>        
        </div>

        <table id="table" ></table>
  </div>
</body>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

       $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "action.php?status",
             dataType: "json",
             contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
             success: function (response, textStatus, xhr) {

                      $.each( xhr.responseJSON.reply, function( index, value ){
                          var matched = value.indexOf("aster");
                          var defaults = matched == 0 ? 'selected' : '';
                          $('#jails').append($('<option></option>').val(value).html(value));  
                      });                    
             }  
       });

      $('#jails').change(function(){
           var jail = "";
           var url = "action.php?status";
           $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {       jail = $( this ).text(); });

           $.table.bootstrapTable('refresh', {
                url: url + "&jail=" + jail ,
                refreshOptions: {url: url + "&jail=" + jail
               }
            });
      });

//other code for table
$table.bootstrapTable(tableConfig);
//other code for table
});
```

i try access to select with id jails, with lot of ways, for example

```
$(document).find("#jails") - In Chrome DevTools shows all dynamic options, but wont accessible(
$(document).find("#jails").children() - nothing
    $(document).on('all.bs.table', function (e, name, args) {
      //load-success.bs.table
      console.log(name, args);
      if(name == 'reset-view.bs.table'){
        $(document).find("#jails").children();
      }
    })
```

**Solved**

```
...
      $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "action.php?status",
             async: false, 
...
});
```

async mode is enabled by default if not set to false.
after set ajax async to false, dynamic elements now is available.
Thx all for help.

Comment: `$('#jails').val()`

Comment: $('#jails').val() is null (

Comment: Hi, that select-box is added by you or you are using some plugin for that ? Also, does your `$('#jails').change(function(){` gets called or not ?

Comment: @Swati - div with class .toolbar and children select-box this is custom element added by me for bootstrap-table plugin.  $('#jails').change working correct

Comment: So, in `$('#jails').change` you are not to get the selected value ?

Comment: In `$('#jails').change` i get selected value only when #jails is changed and it works . but when it try to set default(selected value after ajax) appended data not accessible

Comment: Hi, after appending your option inside `$.each(..`  just add next line   : `$("#jails option:last").prop("selected", matched == 0 ? true : false);`

Comment: @Swati, i tried add you code to `$.each` section in ajax request but no effect